# Float number stored not as the input

Tags: c

I'm trying to input a float from the user, with 3 digit after the dot (353.624):

```
scanf("%f", &number);
```

But it store it as 353.623993

To emphasize - I don't try to divided, just to store the number.

I cant find my mistake :(

Hope you can help me
Thanks a lot

Comment: Which type is `number`?

Comment: number is float, I have to use float...

Comment: `float` typically employs 32-bits.  Certainly a `float` cannot encode every possible number _exactly_.  353.623992919921875 is the closest approximation.